# Placing a single X and a single Y axis to a group of plots

Tags: graphics, code-request

I have the following 4 plots sharing a common X and Y axes. I place 4 plots in a grid of 2 by 2. I do not want to use separate X and Y-axis labels for each of them. Instead, I want to put a single X-axis and Y-axis for 4 plots in a single frame.

```
    GraphicsGrid[{
  {
   Plot[
        {x, x^3},
        {x, 0, 1},
        Frame -> True,
        PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]
        ],
   Plot[
        {x, x^3},
        {x, 0, 1},
        Frame -> True,
        PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]
        ]},
  {
   Plot[
        {x, x^3},
        {x, 0, 1},
        Frame -> True,
        PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]
        ],
   Plot[
        {x, x^3},
        {x, 0, 1},
        Frame -> True,
        PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]
        ]}
  }, FrameLabel -> {"x-axis", "y-axis"}]
```

I tried to use `ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]` to place X-axis and Y-axis, but I could not do it.

Any help?

[image]

Here is the example to show the format of the axis labels.

[image]

Comment: Could you please draw by hand how the `single-X` and `single-Y` axes will appear on the final plot?

Comment: @Syed: I will do it in a moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have any difficulties with `PlotGrid`:

```
ops = 
 Sequence[
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]
 ];

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{
   Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate @ ops],
   Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate @ ops]},
  {Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate @ ops],
   Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate @ ops]}},
     Spacings -> 10, 
     "ShowFrameLabels" -> Automatic, 
     FrameLabel -> {"x-axis", "y-axis"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Individual plots should be separated with some space and Y-axis and X-axis be placed for the frame of the 4 plots.

Comment: Please see update (`PlotGrid` has many options)

Comment: I am sorry that I could not explain it better. The update is good but still I like to place X-axis label `X-axis` on the horizontal axis and Y-axis label as `Y-axis` on the vertical axis.

Comment: Maybe like the latest revision?

Comment: YES. This is the format.

Answer (score 4):

```
 gg = GraphicsGrid[{
   {Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]], 
    Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]]}, 
   {Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]], 
    Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]]}}];

Labeled[#, {"y-axis", "x-axis"}, {Left, Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True] & @ gg
```

[image]

Add the option `ImageMargins -> 10` to `GraphicsGrid[...]` to get

[image]

***Update:*** To add a legend and a plot label:

```
legend = LineLegend[97, { "I", "S", "R"}, LegendLayout -> "Row"];

Legended[#, Placed[legend, Below]] & @
   Labeled[# , {"Title for the group", "y-axis", "x-axis"}, 
     {Top, Left, Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True] & @ gg
```

[image]

Comment: Treating this group of 4 plots as a single plot, how can I place a single `PlotLabel->"Title for the group"` at the top and a single `PlotLegends->{"I","S","R"}` at the bottom below `X-axis`. Sorry for this extra question which is not in the original question.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, please see the update.

Answer (score 3):

```
Grid[{{Rotate[Text[Style["Y-Axis", 18]], 90*Degree],
   Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]],
   Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]]},
  
  {SpanFromAbove,
   Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]],
   Plot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]]},
  
  {, Text[Style["X-Axis", 18]],
   SpanFromLeft}},
 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center, {Center, Center}},, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]